# Add Proxy-Authorization header in swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I need to add specific header on swagger ui using .net core. Is there any way to include header like this?

Already tried:

- implementing IOperationFilter:

  ```cs
  public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
  {
      if (operation.Parameters == null)
          operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();

      if (operation.Parameters.All(p => p.Name != "Proxy-Authorization"))
      {
          operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
          {
              Name = "Proxy-Authorization",
              In = "header",
              Description = "Proxy-Authorization token",
              Required = true,
              Type = "string"
          });
      }
  }
  ```
- adding security definition:

  ```cs
  options.AddSecurityDefinition("Proxy-Authorization", new ApiKeyScheme()
  {
      In = "header",
      Description = "Please insert Proxy Authorization Secret into field",
      Name = "Proxy-Authorization",
      Type = "apiKey"
  });
  ```

Both didn't work. When I change header name everything work fine, but this specific header is wiped out from a call.

Did you ever meet this issue? How to solve this?

Comment: Did you add your operation filter implementation while enabling swagger?

Comment: Thanks for comment, but yes. Swagger is enabled and operation filter as well, authorization header is working fine. I want to add proxy-authorization alongside with authorization one.

While I was playing with swashbuckle I find out that there is no possibility to add a header with `proxy-` prefix.

Comment: Do you have a minimal project on GitHub? I would like to troubleshoot your issue...

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for interesting in this issue. Please find my repository on [github](https://github.com/meanin/swashbuckle-proxy-authorization-header).
It shows what is going on. I create there only a solution with implementation of IOperationFilter. But both works same.
Best regards

Comment: I entered a bug with the swagger-ui team: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3956

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

A forbidden header name is an HTTP header name that cannot be modified programmatically; specifically, an HTTP request header name.

...

Forbidden header names start with Proxy- or Sec-, or consist of one of these:

- Accept-Charset
- Accept-Encoding
- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Connection
- Content-Length
- Cookie
- Cookie2
- Date
- DNT
- Expect
- Host
- Keep-Alive
- Origin
- Proxy-
- Sec-
- Referer
- TE
- Trailer
- Transfer-Encoding
- Upgrade
- Via

Comment: I saw response on github issue. Thanks.